# Identifying the noun for noun-verb agreement

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

In the following sentence, what is the correct verb to use:

> "We identified $130,000 in costs that [**were/was**] not eligible for reimbursement."

I'm thinking that "*$130,000*" (and not "costs")  is the noun, is this correct?

Comment: *"I'm thinking that "$130,000" (and not "costs") is the noun"* __ You are right @MaryMcCoy. As an ***amount*** it often takes a singular verb, but if you were to say "one hundred and thirty thousand dollars" then it can possibly take a plural verb as an alternative.

Comment: I agree that the main subject is the money (not the costs, which might be thought of as a qualifier). However, my personal preference (in this case, anyway) is to treat the plural dollars as a plural. So, *we identified two* ***dollars*** *in costs that* ***were*** *not eligible for reimbursement* and *we identified one* ***dollar*** *in costs that* ***was*** *not eligible for reimbursement.*